# I am getting Promise <Pending> when using mongoose find() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I have created a function that gets the list of all products from MongoDB. I am using a mongoose package. I am trying to console log it but instead, I am getting Promise . Here is my code: -

```
router.get('/', function (req,res) {

    //Gets all the products being sold by the particular seller
    const allProducts = findAllProducts(userId);
    console.log(allProducts);
})

async function findAllProducts(sellerId) {
    try {
        let products = await Products.find( { seller: {
            Id: sellerId
        }});   
        return products;     
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: As `findAllProducts` is an `async function`, it returns a promise. You'll have to `await` that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move async/await to the route  function:

```
router.get('/', async function (req,res) {

    //Gets all the products being sold by the particular seller
    const allProducts = await findAllProducts(userId);
    console.log(allProducts);
})

function findAllProducts(sellerId) {
    try {
        return Products.find( { seller: {
            Id: sellerId
        }});   

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, you should also move the `try`/`catch` in the route handler - it won't catch any exceptions otherwise.